# How To Fix facebook pixel errors

Tags: facebook-pixel

I set up my facebook pixel for my shopify account, when I created my campaign, conversion for "purchase" it gave me data, but when people click on the ad and buy something from my store, there is a "purchase sign" on my ad set but no purchase on my shopify store...

Then I went to check my facebook pixel, it says that there are two diagnostics I need to fix, it's "purchase" and " adds to cart"

How do I fix this?